# What's exact math behind hue-rotate filter

Tags: svg, svg-filters

In theory for every possible color-altering css [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)s like `grayscale`, `invert`, `opacity`, `saturate`, `sepia` there exist equivalent transformation achievable through svg filter `feColorMatrix`. 
Actually almost all such operations are described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#ShorthandEquivalents).

For instance, sepia is a shorthand for:

```
<filter id="sepia">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
             values="(0.393 + 0.607 * [1 - amount]) (0.769 - 0.769 * [1 - amount]) (0.189 - 0.189 * [1 - amount]) 0 0
                     (0.349 - 0.349 * [1 - amount]) (0.686 + 0.314 * [1 - amount]) (0.168 - 0.168 * [1 - amount]) 0 0
                     (0.272 - 0.272 * [1 - amount]) (0.534 - 0.534 * [1 - amount]) (0.131 + 0.869 * [1 - amount]) 0 0
                     0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
```

With `hue-rotate` though it's slightly more complicated, the actual definition is:

[image]

This is pretty much how it's [implemented](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/platform/graphics/filters/FEColorMatrix.cpp) in Chromium.

My question would be - what is exact math behind this coefficients - why exactly them has been chosen? Do they stand for approximations of some irrational numbers or whatever?

Comment: The values originate from here I think: https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.709-6-201506-I!!PDF-E.pdf

Comment: https://beesbuzz.biz/code/16-hsv-color-transforms